# Detecting nested undefined attributes using command line tools (eslint/standard)

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'd like to be able to use static code analysis tool (standard/eslint) to detect following situation:

```
  const obj = {a: {b: 'just a value'}}
  // should be obj.a.b
  const b = obj.a.c
  // so b will be undefined
```

Both Standard and ESLint will not find any issue here. 
Is it possible to detect it using good code quality tools?

Just to give example, IDEA/Webstorm is reporting the problem correctly
[image]

so, just wondering, is it possible to detect the same issue using command line tools.

Comment: You want raise an exception ?

Comment: @BNilsou yes, I'd like to have warning/error raised by static code quality tool

Comment: I think this article and custom rule might point you in the right direction:

http://blog.cowchimp.com/writing-a-custom-eslint-rule-to-spot-undeclared-props/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static type checkers like [Flow](https://flowtype.org/) or [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html) are designed to catch this class of bugs. Try pasting your example code in either the [try Flow editor](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqWAjAK1AF5QBvAQwC4L9aByQgVx1EtADdLpmBTBgF9BqDG3yk8RAHSVpKIA) or the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20obj%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%20%7Bb%3A%20'just%20a%20value'%7D%7D%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20obj.a.c). Without any modifications to the code to add specific type annotations, both checkers catch the error.

[Flow](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqWAjAK1AF5QBvAQwC4L9aByQgVx1EtADdLpmBTBgF9BqDG3yk8RAHSVpKIA):

```
4: const b = obj.a.c
                   ^ property `c`. Property not found in
4: const b = obj.a.c
             ^ object literal
```

[TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20obj%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%20%7Bb%3A%20'just%20a%20value'%7D%7D%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20obj.a.c):

```
Property 'c' does not exist on type '{ b: string; }'.
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `undefined` is a correct value for variables, so you can't detect an assignment of this value.
For your problem, I suggest you to define a function like this one :

```
const assignNested = function(value) {
  if (value === undefined)
    throw new Error("undefined assignment");
  return value;
}
```

Then you can rewrite your code as followed :

```
const obj = {a: {b: 'just a value'}};
const b = assignNested(obj.a.b); // b = 'just a value'
const c = assignNested(obj.a.c); // raise exception
```

Don't forget to catch your throwed exceptions. If you want define your own exception type, it's possible (take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Error).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not a typed language, so it's not really possible to validate object destructuring before running your code.

For example, when you get a response from an HTTP Request, your code quality tools are not aware of the resulting JSON object.